Android devices rendering blank screen on my react-native app because of react-i18next
So I've been trying to figure out the root of this problem for 2 days now. I finally found it by removing the I18nextProvider wrapper from my App.tsx module. This is odd, because it works perfectly on iOS. However, when I start the application on Android (via expo) - it doesn't render anything except for a blank screen. When I delete the I18nextProvider wrapper, it renders perfectly and even renders the translations after selecting the language on the home screen. After it renders correctly without the I18nextProvider wrapper, I can replace the wrapper and it will continue to work perfectly. I just have to remove the code after starting up the app, or else it won't render. Here is the App.tsx file:
import 'intl-pluralrules'; // Import for pluralization rules
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator'; // Import your navigator
import i18n from './src/i18n'; // Import i18n configuration
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
     <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n} defaultNS={'en'}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
I figured I should go ahead and show code relevant to react-i18n:
i18n.ts:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

import enTranslations from './locales/en/translation.json';
import esTranslations from './locales/es/translation.json';
import frTranslations from './locales/fr/translation.json';
import deTranslations from './locales/de/translation.json';
import zhTranslations from './locales/zh/translation.json';
import jaTranslations from './locales/ja/translation.json';
import arTranslations from './locales/ar/translation.json';
import hiTranslations from './locales/hi/translation.json';

export const resources = {
  en: { translation: enTranslations },
  es: { translation: esTranslations },
  fr: { translation: frTranslations },
  de: { translation: deTranslations },
  zh: { translation: zhTranslations },
  ja: { translation: jaTranslations },
  ar: { translation: arTranslations },
  hi: { translation: hiTranslations },
} as const;

export const defaultNS = 'translation';

const initI18n = async () => {
  // Retrieve saved language or default to device language
  const savedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
  const locales = Localization.getLocales();
  const initialLanguage = savedLanguage || (locales.length > 0 ? locales[0].languageCode : 'en');

  // Ensure 'initialLanguage' is a string
  if (!initialLanguage) {
    throw new Error('Initial language must be a valid string');
  }

  i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
      resources,
      lng: initialLanguage as string, // Cast to string
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
      react: { useSuspense: false }
    } as any); // Cast to any to bypass TypeScript errors
};

initI18n();

export default i18n;

i18next.d.ts:
    import "i18next";
    import { resources, defaultNS } from "../i18n";

    declare module "i18next" {
    interface CustomTypeOptions {
        defaultNS: typeof defaultNS;
        resources: typeof resources["en"];
    }
    }

tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "@firebase/auth": ["./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/index.rn.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/types",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

